# Understanding Context API caveat

Tags: reactjs

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats) there is a caveat when using the Context API and the proposed solution is to lift up the provider's value into its parent's state. How does this help with performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because lifting the provider's value into its parent state memoizes the value when it passes it as a prop. So if a child component of the provider were to be memoized (eg. wrapped in `React.memo`) the child wouldn't re-render every time the provider re-renders.

If the value isn't an object, then it doesn't need to be memoized

Comment: Note: This is only true if your value is an object type (which TBH is probably the most common). But yea, this answer is 100% correct.

Comment: Ah good point. I'll add "if the value isn't an object, then it doesn't need to be memoized"